# Init viewcontroller in app delegate, including tableview delegates

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a view controller class in my app:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var usersTable: UITableView!

var pendingRequest: FBRequest?
var pendingLoginForSlot: Int!
var userID: String?
var swipeGesture: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    usersTable.delegate = self
    usersTable.dataSource = self
    self.pendingLoginForSlot = -1
    self.usersTable.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

I want this view controller to be initialized and completely functional in my app delegate after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` When I define this view controller in the app delegate like so:

```
var VC: ViewController = ViewController()
```

The `VC.usersTable` is nil. But when I do my function after `viewDidLoad` everything is working fine.

So how can I fire functions from within app delegate (e.g. logging in users that are defined in the tableview) and thus have the properties available that get defined in `viewDidLoad` and expect the same results after I load the VC in a regular manner by loading it via a tab barcontroller?

Thanks!

Comment: When you instantiate a new `ViewController` like that it isn't linked to your storyboard, so the IBoutlets will be nil.  Assuming that the ViewController instance is your initial view comtroller in your storyboard then it will be available via the rootviewcontroller property of your window

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your prompt reply. DO you have an idea about how I can instantiate the view controller which is linked to the storyboard, so including all the bells and whistles, so the speak. Thanks!

Comment: The framework will instantiate your initial view controller for you.  in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you can access it via `application.keyWindow.rootViewController`.  Note that if your `ViewController` instance is embedded in a tab bar controller, then the root view controller will be the tab bar controller and you will need to go into it's `viewControllers` property